# How to calculate the sum of all values per month of a JSON file in React and display it as a single month using ChartJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, chart.js

First of all I would like to apologize in case I didn't elaborate my question in the best way, as a junior developer there are times when I find it hard to ask the right question, I guess we all have been there right?

The information in my JSON file looks like this:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"Period From": "2021-01-31T23:00:00.00.000Z",
"Period To": "2021-02-27T23:00:00:00.000Z",
"Transaction Date": null,
"Distributor": "DistributeName",
"UPC": "UpcNumber",
"cat. no.": "CatNumber",
"ISRC": "IsrcNumber",
"Label": "LabelName",
"Release Title": "ReleaseTitle",
"Track Title": "TrackTitle",
"Mix Name": "Original Mix",
"Artist": "ArtistName",
"Territory": "US",
"Quantity": "2
"Revenue": "0.001091
},
{
"id": 2,
"Period From": "2021-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
"Period To": "2021-02-27T23:00:00.000Z",
"Distributor": "DistributeName",
"UPC": "UpcNumber",
"cat. no.": "CatNumber",
"ISRC": "IsrcNumber",
"Label": "LabelName",
"Release Title": "ReleaseTitle",
"Track Title": "TrackTitle",
"Mix Name": "Original Mix",
"Artist": "ArtistName",
"Territory": "US",
"Quantity": 4,
"Revenue": 0.002181
},
{
"id": 20,
"Period From": "2021-03-31T22:00:00.000Z",
"Period To": "2021-04-29T22:00:00.000Z",
"Distributor": "DistributeName",
"UPC": "UpcNumber",
"cat. no.": "CatNumber",
"ISRC": "IsrcNumber",
"Label": "LabelName",
"Release Title": "ReleaseTitle",
"Track Title": "TrackTitle",
"Mix Name": "Original Mix",
"Artist": "ArtistName",
"Territory": "US",
"Quantity": 1,
"Revenue": 0.004827
},
{
"id": 2000,
"Period From": "2021-04-29T22:00:00.000Z",
"Period To": "2021-05-26T22:00:00.000Z",
"Distributor": "DistributeName",
"UPC": "UpcNumber",
"cat. no.": "CatNumber",
"ISRC": "IsrcNumber",
"Label": "LabelName",
"Release Title": "ReleaseTitle",
"Track Title": "TrackTitle",
"Mix Name": "Original Mix",
"Artist": "ArtistName",
"Territory": "US",
"Quantity": 4,
"Revenue": 0.002181
},
{
"id": 20,
"Period From": "2021-03-31T22:00:00.000Z",
"Period To": "2021-04-29T22:00:00.000Z",
"Distributor": "DistributeName",
"UPC": "UpcNumber",
"cat. no.": "CatNumber",
"ISRC": "IsrcNumber",
"Label": "LabelName",
"Release Title": "ReleaseTitle",
"Track Title": "TrackTitle",
"Mix Name": "Original Mix",
"Artist": "ArtistName",
"Territory": "US",
"Quantity": 4,
"Revenue": 0.003288
},
{
"id": 2001,
"Period From": "2021-04-29T22:00:00.000Z",
"Period To": "2021-05-26T22:00:00.000Z",
"Distributor": "DistributeName",
"UPC": "UpcNumber",
"cat. no.": "CatNumber",
"ISRC": "IsrcNumber",
"Label": "LabelName",
"Release Title": "ReleaseTitle",
"Track Title": "TrackTitle",
"Mix Name": "Original Mix",
"Artist": "ArtistName",
"Territory": "US",
"Quantity": 1,
"Revenue": 0.000822
},
{
"id": 5010,
"Period From": "2021-04-30T22:00:00.000Z",
"Period To": "2021-05-30T22:00:00.000Z",
"Distributor": "DistributeName",
"UPC": "UpcNumber",
"cat. no.": "CatNumber",
"ISRC": "IsrcNumber",
"Label": "LabelName",
"Release Title": "ReleaseTitle",
"Track Title": "TrackTitle",
"Mix Name": "Original Mix",
"Artist": "ArtistName",
"Quantity": 150,
"Revenue": 0.007441
}
]
```

The above info comes from my table in my database, which is an array of multiple single objects with different ids, I have only published 3 examples but I have more than 100k objects in the same table.

I have a component called LineChart.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import  { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler,
} from 'chart.js';

import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler
);


const LineChart = ({ songs }) => {

  let data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    //  labels: songs?.map((song) => song["Period From"]), // this was my original idea, it works but it shows all the revenues of each individual track on the chart

    datasets: [{
      label: 'Revenue',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 30, 40, 80, 25, 50],
      // data: songs?.map((song) => song.Revenue), // same as above this was my original idea, it works but it shows all the revenues of each individual track on the chart
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.1)',
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "#000",
      ],
      borderWidth: 2,
      tension: 0.1, 
    }]
  };

  let options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
    },
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontSize: 25,
      },
    },
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
      <Line className='p-10'
        data={data}
        height={400}
        options={options}

      />
    </div>
    </div>
    )
}



export default LineChart
```

At the moment it looks like this, which looks like an electrocardiogram. ( I'm not sure if I can make jokes on the platform.)
[current chart look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMN5k.png)

But what I want to achieve is to make it look like this:

[desired chart look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3ZOn.png)

songs is a props that I am passing from another component to call the data from my table in the database.

I need to calculate the values for each month and make the final result for one month, for example:
Period From 01-01-2023 and Period To 31-01-2023="MM/yyyy" or something like that.

I hope you guys will be able to help me and if there is something I have not expressed well please leave me a comment before giving a negative vote. :))

**UPDATE**

Based on @Badacadabra's answer I have done this, but I can only see the revenue in May. I just changed the for loop a bit to make it more understandable for me.

```
const LineChart = ({ songs }) => {

let monthlyTotals = new Array(12).fill(0);

for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
  let obj = songs[i];
  let fromMonth = new Date(obj['Period From']).getMonth();
  let toMonth = new Date(obj['Period To']).getMonth();

  if (fromMonth === toMonth) {
    monthlyTotals[fromMonth] += obj.Quantity * obj.Revenue;
  }
}


  let data = {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],

    datasets: [{
      label: 'Revenue',
      data: monthlyTotals,
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.1)',
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "#000",
      ],
      borderWidth: 2,
      tension: 0.1, 
    }]
  };

  let options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
    },
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontSize: 25,
      },
    },
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
      <Line
        data={data}
        height={400}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

[New Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GnHq.png)

Comment: Is your JSON is a array of objects or array of single object? `id: 1` and `id: 2` are two different arrays with single object.

Comment: @mc-user an array of objects, will change that right away :)

Comment: If you want only one datapoint per month the data array can't have more than 12 items. You'll need to parse you data differently

Comment: @jarne-kompier I need to calculate the values for each month and make the final result for one month, for example, Period From 01-01-2023 and Period To 31-01-2023=" MM/yyyy " or something like that.

Comment: If you can, I think you should refine your database query. In your JSON, you do not have months but periods which may go from one month to another. Given that you have a quantity and a revenue for each object in your array, this data structure will not allow you to calculate monthly totals coherently.

Comment: Thank you very much @badacadabra. Period From and Period To, always goes from the beginning of the month to the end of the month, but always from the same month. How can I modify my database so that it can be done?

Comment: If you can guarantee that your periods are always classified by month, you can do something using JavaScript without modifying your back-end code. Where are you stuck precisely in the implementation?

Comment: @badacadabra tried your code on codesandbox but somehow when I add new data into the array, I just can't see it on the chart.

Comment: I guess some of your periods are filtered by this condition: `fromMonth === toMonth`. Can I see a larger subset of your data? And if you share a link with what you have tried, it would be ideal. (By the way, be careful with this syntax: `new Array(12).fill(0)`. There is absolutely no problem here, but keep in mind that this is **far** slower in terms of performance. Within a huge loop, I think it makes a quite significant difference. For the record, the standard `for` loop that you use is also slightly faster than `for...of`, but here the gap is minimal.)

Comment: @badacadabra Oki, I'll add it again as you did :) I just added new data in the array, could you check if it's enough? If you need more let me know, please. Thank you very much for helping me with this, I'm having a hard time.

Comment: Take a look at the object whose id is 5010. The quantity is much higher there (150), which may explain why you get a peak in may. Have you tried to remove `obj.Quantity` from the formula as suggested in my answer? Try this instead: `monthlyTotals[fromMonth] += obj.Revenue;`. Besides, could you give me the unit of `obj.Revenue`?

Comment: @badacadabra this works: ```monthlyTotals[fromMonth] += obj.Revenue``` :D Thank you so much for your patience. :))

Comment: You're welcome! ;) There is a little typo in my previous comment, but you understood what I meant... *The quantity is much higher there (150), which may explain why you get a peak in **M**ay.*

Comment: @badacadabra yes no worries. And I understand what you mean now about the chart loading slowly when the data increases. I have to think about how to fix this.

Comment: As I said previously, I think the best way would be to aggregate your data from the back-end. Making heavy calculations with front-end code may have a strong impact on user experience. Technical solutions exist, like [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API), but sometimes it is just more efficient to run a script outside a browser environment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a strategy to preprocess your data. Here is a simple implementation:

```js
// Declare and initialize an array containing 12 values (because there are 12 months)
let monthlyTotals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

// Loop through the data array
for (let obj of data) {
  // Parse date strings and get month number (0 is January and 11 is December)
  let fromMonth = new Date(obj['Period From']).getMonth(),
      toMonth = new Date(obj['Period To']).getMonth();
   
  // Make sure that your period is correct to avoid an inconsistent result   
  if (fromMonth === toMonth) {
    // Use the month number as an index to update the right value in monthlyTotals
    monthlyTotals[fromMonth] += obj.Quantity * obj.Revenue;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I use this formula to update monthly totals: `obj.Quantity * obj.Revenue`. If `obj.Quantity` is not relevant in your case, for instance if `obj.Revenue` already takes into account the quantity, you can remove it easily and just keep what you need.

I created sample data for the first three months to give you a full example:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Period From": "2022-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Period To": "2023-01-30T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Revenue": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Period From": "2022-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Period To": "2023-01-30T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Quantity": 4,
    "Revenue": 7
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "Period From": "2022-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Period To": "2023-01-30T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Revenue": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "Period From": "2023-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Period To": "2023-02-27T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Quantity": 5,
    "Revenue": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "Period From": "2023-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Period To": "2023-02-27T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Quantity": 3,
    "Revenue": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "Period From": "2023-02-28T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Period To": "2023-03-30T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Revenue": 10
  }
];

let monthlyTotals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    
for (let obj of data) {
  let fromMonth = new Date(obj['Period From']).getMonth(),
      toMonth = new Date(obj['Period To']).getMonth();
      
   if (fromMonth === toMonth) {
     monthlyTotals[fromMonth] += obj.Quantity * obj.Revenue;
   }
}

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Revenue',
      data: monthlyTotals,
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: true
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Given that you dataset is big, you may face performance issues. If this occurs, you should preprocess from the back-end.

Comment: Thank you so much @badacadabra this really works :D but somehow I see only revenue in May. Could you please look at the update I put with your code? Where did I make the mistake?